# Slack reminder for every other weekday

Tags: slack, reminders

Like the title says I would like to be reminded by slack of having Bug Support every other weekday.
I tried `/remind me BugSupport every second weekday` but this reminds me every weekday! 
Alternative solutions are also welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Currently Slack doesnt handle every alternate weekday.... however you can try by explictly mentioning every weekday.... I know its but cumbersome (and just a workaround) but it does the trick for me.... hope it helps..

/remind me BugSupport every other Monday
/remind me BugSupport every other Tuesday

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is now supported? About to try it myself!
https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/1019954365484937216?lang=en